# what does anonymous mean in C stack

Tags: android, gdb, stack

I got a very weird stack from android:

```
Cmd line: /system/bin/mediadrmserver
ABI: 'arm'

"mediadrmserver" sysTid=865
  #00 pc 000000c4  <anonymous:eed0a000>
  #01 pc 000000c3  <anonymous:eed0a000>
```

I never saw such stack before, does anonymous means this stack actually has been corrupted? how can I analyze it?